# Warning after publishing app to app store: "This app references non-public sectors"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I successfully published my app, but got this warning:

[image: https://pp.vk.me/c619829/v619829393/b1f6/10V0BLT3tgI.jpg]

I don't have any warnings at build time. What should I do here?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It is similar, but the referenced selectors are different. While in this case, we can be sure that there is no problem, the referenced question has a lot more selectors that might cause trouble when submitting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are probably using MagicalRecord and can safely ignore this warning.